How to disable the caret (^) characters in the Python stacktrace?
I have a script for doing test readouts that worked fine with Python 3.9 but now we upgraded to Python 3.12 we have those carets that break the script. So the easiest way would be disabling it.
Is there a way to disable the carets (^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^) in the Python stacktrace?
ERROR: test_email (tests.test_emails.EmailTestCase.test_email)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/my-project/email/tests/test_emails.py", line 72, in test_email
    self.assertNotEquals(self.email.id, self.email_id)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


I don't think there's any way to customize backtraces. Why do you want to disable the part that tells you precisely where the error is?

This sounds like an XY Problem.  Why do you think you need to do this?  What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

You could wrap all your code in your own try/except that implements a custom backtrace.

Oh! I have a script for doing test readouts that worked fine with Python 3.9 but now we upgraded to Python 3.12 we have those carets that break the script. So the easiest way would be disabling it.

@claudius: Seems like the easier solution is to adjust the script to ignore the "spaces-and-carets-only" lines. Or preprocess the output to do the same. They're not super-concerned with backwards-compatibility with traceback formats in this scenario (where the carets are an objective improvement in every way aside from perfect text compatibility).

Running Python with the -X no_debug_ranges flag or the PYTHONNODEBUGRANGES environment variable set should normally disable this, but I'm not sure about if that'll work with unit tests, and other traceback improvements may not be affected. Long term, you'll probably have to adjust your script.

FWIW, IPython's traceback formatters don't include the carets, but they also add some other stuff like extra line breaks.

You can run Python with the -X no_debug_ranges command-line option, or set the PYTHONNODEBUGRANGES environment variable (to any nonempty string) before running your program, to disable these indicators.

Do these options support disabling only certain portions of the stack trace message, like carets, or does it disable the stack trace message entirely?

@RandallArms Read the links; they explain.

I did, and I believe I lack some of the necessary fundamental understanding of the phrases used on that page, hence why I posed a more direct question to you. I was hoping that you'd give me a direct answer and expand my understanding.

@RandallArms: Specifically the carets, the part the questioner was trying to disable.

@RandallArms I'm not user2357112, but nbd. The important part from the links is "suppressing the extra visual location indicators when the interpreter displays tracebacks". The "visual location indicators" are the carets.

Thank you both for your clarifications. I think this is the better answer than my own, then.

That's worked great! Thanks!!
We exported the PYTHONNODEBUGRANGES = True.

If you're using Python 3.13 or above, where the traceback module is used by default over the C implementation for formatting exceptions, you can override traceback.StackSummary.format_frame_summary with one that removes column information from the given frame summary so that the frames would be formatted without carets:
import traceback

class SimpleStackSummary(traceback.StackSummary):
    def format_frame_summary(self, frame_summary, **kwargs):
        frame_summary.colno = None
        return super().format_frame_summary(frame_summary, **kwargs)

traceback.StackSummary = SimpleStackSummary

so that:
1 / 0

outputs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    1 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero


Why and how to hide the Python stack trace
"You can do this by setting sys.excepthook to a custom callable, and use sys.__excepthook__ to print the stack trace only under some conditions:"
import sys

SHOW_STACK_TRACE = False

def on_crash(exctype, value, traceback):
    if SHOW_STACK_TRACE:
        sys.__excepthook__(exctype, value, traceback)
    else:
        print('Actionable error message')

sys.excepthook = on_crash

You could then take the error message, edit out characters you don't want like carets with a regex, and finally spit it back out in your custom callable for sys.excepthook.

You could reimplement sys.excepthook() without the indicators.
You can use the traceback module to do a lot of the heavy lifting.
import sys
import traceback

# Typing
from types import TracebackType

HEADER = "Traceback (most recent call last):"
FRAME_TEMPLATE = "  File {filename!r}, line {lineno}, in {name}"
LINE_TEMPLATE = "    {line}"

def excepthook(
        _etype: type[BaseException],  # Ignored
        value: BaseException,
        tb: TracebackType | None
        ) -> None:
    stack: traceback.StackSummary = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
    sys.stderr.write(HEADER + '\n')
    frame: traceback.FrameSummary
    for frame in stack:
        sys.stderr.write(
            FRAME_TEMPLATE.format(
                filename=frame.filename,
                lineno=frame.lineno,
                name=frame.name) + '\n')
        if frame.line:  # Null in REPL
            sys.stderr.write(LINE_TEMPLATE.format(line=frame.line) + '\n')
    traceback.print_exception(value, limit=0)

Example usage:
sys.excepthook = excepthook

def f():
    return 1 / 2 / 0

f() | f()

Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 'tmp.py', line 41, in <module>
    f() | f()
  File 'tmp.py', line 39, in f
    return 1 / 2 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Compared to the normal output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 41, in <module>
    f() | f()
    ^^^
  File "tmp.py", line 39, in f
    return 1 / 2 / 0
           ~~~~~~^~~
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Note: I'm not sure I caught all the edge cases. For one, I was originally using print(file=sys.stderr) instead of sys.stderr.write(), but then I got worried about someone monkey-patching builtins.print.

P.S. I ran this on Python 3.12, if that's relevant.

On further testing, this doesn't work properly for exceptions where "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred". It shows the "other" traceback in place of the "above" traceback.
